# Email to multiple Users via Send Grid APis

Tags: python, django, sendgrid

I am new to Django and stared my first app in django, I am sending emails to my user's on specific events. I am using SendGrid APIs for sending emails. I have wrote the following code to send emails to single users, that is working for me. but want to send emails to multiple users at once. I also have a table for users's. I need to **fetch all user's from database in a list and send them email at once.**

Note that i had just started to learn django, and little knowledge about django orm.

Here is the function for getting message subject and content from users via html form and send to single user. for now i have hard coded the recipient email.

```
def send_message(request):
    Message_Subject = str(request.POST.get('Subject'))
    Message_Content = str(request.POST.get('Content'))
    Message_Type = str(request.POST.get('optionsRadios'))
    Message.objects.create(MessageSubject= Message_Subject, MessageContent=Message_Content)
    sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient(settings.SENDGRID_USERNAME, settings.SENDGRID_PASSWORD)
    message = sendgrid.Mail()
    message.add_to('user@bar.com')
    message.set_subject(Message_Subject)
    message.set_html(Message_Content)
    message.set_text(Message_Content)
    message.set_from('Emailer System <foo@example.com>')
    status, msg = sg.send(message)
    if status == 200:
        messages.success(request, 'Your email was successfully sent.')
    else:
        messages.error(request, msg)
    return render_to_response('send_message.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is my model.py file

from django.db import models

```
class Users(models.Model):
    UserID = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='User ID',max_length=255,primary_key=True,blank=True)
    UserName = models.CharField(verbose_name='User Name',max_length=254,null=True,blank=True)
    Email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Email',max_length=254,null=True,blank=True)
    Phone = models.CharField(verbose_name='Phone Number',max_length=254,null=True,blank=True)

class Message(models.Model):
    MessageID = models.AutoField(verbose_name='Message ID',primary_key=True)
    MessageSubject = models.CharField(verbose_name='Subject',max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    MessageContent = models.TextField(verbose_name='Content',null=True,blank=True)
    MessageType = models.CharField(verbose_name='Message Type',max_length=255,default='Email',null=True,blank=True)

class Log_Messages(models.Model):
    LogID = models.AutoField(verbose_name='Log ID',primary_key=True)
    MessageID = models.ForeignKey(Message,verbose_name='Message ID',null=True, blank=True)
    UserID = models.ForeignKey(Users,verbose_name='User ID',null=True, blank=True)
    Status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    SentDateTime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), blank=None, null=None)
```

Comment: message.add_to('taqi.hassan@cogilent.com') 
Can u try to pass list of email addresses like ["abc@gmail.com","xyz@gmail.com", ...] in above statement.
It is working for me- for smtplib which is python lib for send email.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do, is put your email sending code in a loop, and read from the database.  You should use the form api that comes with django (see [*Working with Forms*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/) in the documentation) to make your life easier when processing user input.

Here is a complete example to help you get started.

Your models, where `Recipient` is an end user. I have also linked it to the message so you can record the status of delivery for each recipient per message:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    mtype = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(('1','Normal Message'),
                                                    ('2','Other Message'),))
class Recipient(models.Model):
   email = models.EmailField()
   message = models.ForeignKey(Message)
   delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   status = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

Next step is to create a form for your Message model. You can put this in your `views.py` but the convention is to create a new file called `forms.py` and place it there. Make sure you import your models:

```
from .models import Message


class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
```

Now in your view, you will use the form to collect the message to be sent, and then loop through the recipients and send each one a message. The status for each delivery is logged with the recipient model.

Finally, as this is a post request, you should redirect the user (not reload the page).

```
def send_message(request):
    form = MessageForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.save() # This the new message object that was
                           # saved from the data in the form.

        sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient(settings.SENDGRID_USERNAME,
                                     settings.SENDGRID_PASSWORD)

        for user in Recipient.objects.all():  # Loop through all users.
            message = sendgrid.Mail()
            message.add_to(user.email)  # Fetch the email address for each user.
            message.set_subject(data.subject)
            message.set_html(data.content)
            message.set_text(data.content)
            message.set_from('Django Mailer <foo@example.com>')
            status, msg = sg.send(message)
            if status == 200:
                user.received = True
            else:
                user.received = False
            user.message = data # Log which message was sent to this user
            user.status = msg # Log any error message from Sendgrid
            user.save()
         return redirect('/thank-you/')  # Redirect to some thank you page.

    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I understand your logics for message model, form and function. But didn't understand the Recipient model. Can you bit explain what will be its role?

Comment: Have a look at the question now i have updated. I have users table where all the information is stored. Now i just wanted to get message from admin whatever he typed and then sent to to each users in the table and maintain a log for these messages. i have done this in asp.net but i am new to django so i need some help/guidance in my first app.

Comment: The recipient model stores the email address and for each email address, it stores a link to the message and status of delivery, along with any error message. It acts as a logger for transmissions. I think surely you can figure out the rest from the example I gave? Is there a specific question that you have?

Comment: Thanks, but one last help. Can you tell me how to write custom sql queries in django to get data from database. like we done in mysql. E.g Select * from users and store these information in python list.

Comment: Please go through the [Playing with the API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api) section of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call `add_to` for each your email.

```
... 

message = sendgrid.Mail()
user_emails = Users.objects.filter(is_active=True).values_list('email', flat=True)

for email in user_emails:
    message.add_to(email)

message.set_subject(Message_Subject)
...
```